# Tankless water heater - Electric issue

Tags: electrical, water, circuit-breaker, heater, tankless

I have a AuqaPower Tankless water heater I installed myself 2 years ago. 
I used the old wire from old (tank) water heater and I ran a new wire for the 2nd place.
It has worked great for 2 years and never an issue, 2 nights ago while cooking I noticed the water was really hot and had to turn it down. About 30 min later my son went to take a bath and no hot water. 
I checked breaker and it was not tripped- the next day I even changed out the breaker. 
I tested the 2 lines (before changing breaker) going into the water heater and the new line is getting juice but the old wire is showing none. 
Does anyone know what could be the problem? 
I am very handy around the house and I have pretty much remodeled my whole house with the help from my dad- but this has me stumped!!

Comment: I hope you earthed all that....

Comment: Is there a different term for "earthed" I have never heard of such.

Comment: Donno, you got a 3rd wire that is connected to all the metal pipes, containers that runs back to your earth leakage in the distribution box??? If you ever got a short in the water it could electrocute anybody touching the water or taps.

Comment: Yes everything is grounded.

Comment: You said you used an old wire from the old Tank water heater and ran one new wire. Was the old wire sized appropriately for the new water heater? A 50 Gallon 4500W water heater might use a 30A breaker and 10 gauge wire. A 4 - 5 gpm Tankless water heater can be rated for 20,000+ Watts and require a 100+ amp circuit and #6 wire (or larger). If your old wiring is undersized, that could be the source of your problem (as well as a serious fire hazard). Did you need to upsize the breaker the old wiring was connected to?

Comment: I think when you say "wire" you mean cable, e.g. NM cable.  I am guessing this is a heater that has 2 separate heating elements on 2 separate circuits.  Check behind the breaker for a burned bus connection, otherwise it's either the old wire run or the heater itself.  The old wire was the correct size for the breaker, yes?

Comment: First your question does not give enough information to give you an accurate answer. If i had to guess i might say that the earth is called an earth ground which is correct in any home because at some point all grounds lead to a grounding rod driven 8 foot into the ground. your other 2 wires are 110 volts each which running to the same appliance or circuit will give you a total of 220 volts. if one wire is dead nothing will work at all due to low voltage. follow the dead wire back and find out where the problem originates. good luck...